# Use AWS lambda function to convert S3 file from zip to gzip using boto3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gzip, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to convert a .zip file from S3 to a .gzip file using boto3 python in an AWS lambda function. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import json
import boto3
import zipfile
import gzip

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    try: 
        s3Obj = s3.Object(bucket_name=bucket, key=key)
        response = s3Obj.get()
        data = response['Body'].read()
        zipToGzip = gzip.open(data, 'wb')
        zipToGzip.write(s3.upload_file(bucket, (s3 + '.gz')))
        zipToGzip.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Comment: More details and your current code would help. Do you want to re-upload the file to S3 gziped, or just do something with it locally gzipped? Why does it have to be a lambda function? Do you mean python lambda, or AWS lambda?

Comment: I mean AWS Lambda Function using python as it is supported now. I have a file on S3 that is in .zip format, I need to change it to .gzip format.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. What happens with the current code? Does it raise an exception, or not do what you want...?

Comment: In that current code, when it gets to the zipToGzip = gzip.open(data, 'wb') piece, it errors saying:

file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

Comment: Sounds like either the S3 object doesn't exist, or the bucket / key are incorrect? Or could be a permission issue on the object possibly. I'd suggest checking that, and printing out `data` to verify what is there.

Comment: The object does exist and the bucket and key are correct. I can see these from the AWS console. Permissions are also set correctly and roles and policies are in place. Not sure what the issue here is. As a side note, I was able to accomplish this same task using Java, just can't duplicate it with Python.

Answer (score 11):

OK, got it figured out. Thanks for your input Lee.

```
import json
import boto3
import zipfile
import gzip

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    try: 
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, '/tmp/file.zip')
        zfile = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/file.zip')
        namelist = zfile.namelist()

        if len(namelist) >1:
            pass
            #alertme()

        for filename in namelist:
            data = zfile.read(filename)
            f = open('/tmp/' + str(filename), 'wb')
            f.write(data)
            f.close()

        zipToGzip = gzip.open('/tmp/data.gz', 'wb')
        zipToGzip.write(data)
        zipToGzip.close()
        s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/data.gz', bucket, key + '.gz')
        s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Comment: What was the issue? Quite a few changes in your code. But saving the object to a temporary file fixed it?

Comment: @Lee, I'm pretty sure the issue is that the Boto3 object isn't being read correctly as binary. So Scotty is having to download the file from the S3 bucket, instead of using `response['Body'].read()` with a get - which should be the binary file contents. I'm having the same issue - trying to print `response['Body'].read()` just gives me the string "PK". Not sure what this means. Having to pull from the bucket is pretty annoying.

Comment: You can accept your answer to your own question if you like